# Number of Unique Ranks of High Card in Three Card Brag

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, card-games

Well the game is called [Teen Patti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teen_patti#Probabilities) in India. Almost similar to [Three Card Brag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_card_brag) a British game.
There are total $16440$ Unique High Card hands are present. (Considering the suit.)

Hand $1 = 5$ Heart, $3$ Club, $2$ Diamond.

Hand $2$ = $5$ Club, $3$ Diamond, $2$ Heart.

Both these hands belong to High Card Hand Category.
But these hands are ranked same. (There will be a tie between two players, if they have these hand.)

$5$-Heart, $3$-Club, $2$-Diamond is ranked lower than 
$6$-Heart, $4$-Spade, $2$-Club.

What will be the Total Unique Ranks present in High Card Category?

Comment: It is better if you can actually define the problem rather than requiring people to leave the site to find out the definitions. You have neither defined "Rank" nor "High Card Category."

Comment: @ThomasAndrews This question is tagged 'card-games' and the game in question is related to poker. Anyone familiar with poker (or card games in general) should know what 'rank' and 'high-card' mean.

Comment: @Logophobic You can tell me what a *hand* being in "High Card Hand Category" means based on basic understanding of cards? I'm pretty good with card games - kind of well known in the world that intersects math and bridge, even been mentioned in the New York Times bridge column, but I can't tell.

Comment: Well, If I can know how many HighCard Hands will exist if we consider all suit to be same.

Comment: My interpretation of the question for how many "high card categories" there are, letting $H$ be the set of all high-card hands, and $\sim$ be the equivalence relation "is considered equal to in terms of scoring", the question is to find $|H/\sim|$.  I.e. the number of "different" hands which are not pairs, triple, flushes, straights, etc...

Comment: @JMoravitz What is a "high card hand"? Does the ranking go past the top card - is $642$ bigger than $632$, for example?

Comment: @JMoravitz Correct. Thats what the target is

Comment: @ThomasAndrews A 'high-card hand' is any hand that has no pair, set, straight, flush or other higher value.

Comment: A hand which does not fall under the category of a stronger scoring hand such as a pair, three of a kind, straight, flush, or straightflush.  I.e. a hand in which all cards appearing are -distinct numbers, -not consecutive numbers, -not all the same suit.

Comment: As for calculating, really, just consider all suits the same and ignore the condition that you wish to avoid flushes (as any hand can be forced to not be a flush by changing one of the suits and suits are irrelevant to scoring otherwise).  How many ways can you pick three distinct numbers where order doesn't mater?  How many of those ways were bad and would have resulted in a straight?  Apply inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: Do both ace,two, three and queen,king, ace count as straights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $\binom{13}{3}$ ways to choose $3$ distinct ranks. Exactly $12$ of these will be straights (i.e. $A23\cdots QKA$) an must be excluded. There are $274$ distinct high-card hands in $3$-card poker.$$\binom{13}{3}-12=274$$
Another way to arrive at the same result, knowing that there are $16,440$ unique high-card hands, is to divide by the number of ways $(4^4-4=60)$ that such a hand is not a flush: $\frac{16440}{60}=274$. This is also the number of distinct flushes (rank of flush, disregarding suit): $\frac{1096}{4}=274$

Comment: 274, thats exactly what I got. But one of my friend argued and showed me that he got the answer as 275 on counting. What he did is, first card can be 5 - 14 (A), based on the first card, the second card can only be less than first card, (also greater than equal to 3, otherwise third card won't be possible without repetition).  Then based on the second card, third card will be less than 2nd Card and greater than equal to 2. The final count comes up as 275.(After excluding the straights) Where am messing up ? Any combination that will be counted twice in this procedure ?

Comment: Your friend probably forgot to remove both ace straights.

Comment: Yeah, I just saw...On Counting, he was also counting 14(A), 3, 2.  While this is also a straight and should be excluded out. Thanks @ThomasAndrews for quick help.